# Setting CacheControl on Azure blockBlob, how to invalidate when new files are deployed?

Tags: c#, http, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to cache some static blobs we have on azure via:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("staticJsonFile");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobref);

// Cache setup
int expirationSeconds = new DateTime(2050, 1, 1).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds;
string cacheControl = string.Format("public, max-age={0}, s-maxage={0}", expirationSeconds);
blockBlob.Properties.CacheControl = cacheControl;
blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

They are cached "forever".

When new files with the same name (same files but new content) are uploaded to Azure filestorage, can I somehow say that the cache of the blockBlob is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting client side cache control headers as well (`public, max-age=`), even if you invalidate the server blob cache, the client is not going to check for new files. They will just use the cached version.

You should think about adding a version numbers to your files, and update your source references accordingly.

One other way is to force the clients to issue an `if-modified-since` request (which needs you adding `must-revalidate` to your cache control header), so you have a finer control on when a client gets the new file. But you can't use it in your current case as you can't do anything for all browser/apps that have already cached your file.

Forced cache revalidation also results in extra round trips (resulting in http-302 when it's not modified), and can have performance problems if network latency is high.

Comment: OK to sum up your answer I do not use this feature as our filename are always the same and we can not change them, as they are given to us... We do caching now with MemoryCache before we call the azure blob client that saves us unneeded requests with the azure client , even better!